# How do I run a script in VS before publishing web site to Azure?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure

I am currently building an ASP.Net Web Pages site in Visual Studio. I am using the "Publish" context menu functionality to push this up to an Azure Web Site.

However, I want to copy all my assets (from a particular directory in the Web Site project) up to a blob storage bucket before publishing the site. Is there a way to integrate running a script in the publishing process that would perform this task before pushing the site up to Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the Azure Project node in Solution Explorer, Properties, Build Events, Pre-build event command line. You can put a command there that executes your script. The Publish will trigger the build that will trigger your pre-build script.